# How can I convert all the html files I get into text files after a wget command?

Tags: bash, wget, lynx

How can I convert all the html files I get into plain text files after a wget command?

I'm thinking of using *lynx* to convert html files into ".txt" files, getting rid of tags.

I have this snippet to save an entire website, but how can I change it so that  it leaves only the text files that are converted from html files on the website "foobar", in my local folder "test"?

```
wget -P /test/ --recursive http://foobar.html
```

I'm not sure how to **pipe this to *lynx*** and how to specify **applying commands for all the files under some specific directory**.

Comment: What do you mean by text file? you mean to save the file with an extention `.txt`?

Comment: @Vikyboss Yes! As plain text files.

Comment: if I am understanding correctly what you want, go check [**html2text**](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text). By the way, with today's web 2.0 websites, your success will be very spotty if any.

Comment: @Vikyboss I mean text files that got rid of the tags from the original html files.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` may not be the proper tool.  Lynx can download the files and convert them to plain text at the same time, but would do that by redirecting its output to a file.  Because it has no `-output` option, that makes it a little awkward to use in a script, since you would have to assign output names.

But supposing that you had a directory full of `.html` files, then you could use `find` to traverse that directory and convert the files, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -name '*.htm*' | while IFS= read path
do
    lynx -dump "$path" >"${path%%.htm*}.txt"
done
```

to put the ".txt" files in the same tree, or

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -name '*.htm*' | while IFS= read path
do
    target=${path/foobar/test}
    lynx -dump "$path" >"${target%%.htm*}.txt"
done
```

in the folder "test" (mapping "foobar" to "test").  The "/" substitution is bash-specific, not in POSIX (but if you chose to use POSIX, `sed` works well enough).

Further reading:

- [2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (POSIX)

Comment: How can I specify the folder that has html files I want to convert? By making the part ' *.htm*' into '/test/*.htm*'?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just download them as HTML files as planned, then use the command-line utility `html2text`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015809/html2text-convert-special-characters